# Lambda does not send message to SQS destination if invoked by an SQS source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sqs

I have the following set up:

[image: SQS#1 -> Lambda -> SQS#2]

I have a simple return in my Lambda function right now:

```
async function handler(event) {
  return 'success';
}
```

If I invoke the lambda from the aws-cli using:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name tt-yt-automation-production-1b2b-tiktok-download --invocation-type Event --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out /dev/null
```

It will return the message to the destination SQS (`SQS#2`), which will trigger another Lambda.

However, if `SQS#1` has a message and invokes the Lambda, it does not send a message to `SQS#2` and invokes the next Lambda in line.

My suspicion is that an SQS invocation doesn't count as an `asynchronous invocation` and won't send a message to `SQS#2`.

Is there a configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My suspicion is that an SQS invocation doesn't count as an asynchronous invocation and won't send a message to SQS#2.

You are correct. SQS invocation is **synchronous**. You have to "manually" (using AWS SDK) submit messages from your lambda to your SQS#2.

Comment: Just reconfigured my terraform configs and can confirm this to be true.